# Reading elements of a .txt file to create transactions with input

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that gets values of a String to create transactions of two bank accounts. I read a .txt file and saved each line in an entry of an `ArrayList<String>`. 
Each line has its own task. Best to explain with an example .txt file:

```
2
Alice 50
Bob 70
1
Alice Bob 20 This is my reason for the transaction.
```

```
    Line 1: first line marks the amount of accounts that are involved in the transactions followed.
    Line 2-3: The following two lines are two accounts with the given balance.
    Line 4: indicates the amount of transactions followed.
    Line 5: meant to be like: Bob transfers amount 20 to Alices account with an optional 
            note ("This is my reason for the transaction.")
```

This is how i approached the problem: I have created a class `Account` which has a `String holder` and a `int balance`. I managed to separate the lines 2-3 by using a the `String.split(" ")` method. But the next problem I could not handle is the transaction followed. I created a `class` called `Transaction` with one of the following constructors.

```
String receiver;
String sender;
int amount;
int timestamp;
String note;

public Transaction (String receiver, String sender, int amount, String note) {
    this.receiver = receiver; 
    this.sender = sender;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.note = note;
}
```

The Problem I have is that I want to perform the transaction(s) but do not know how to handle the `note` part of the line 5. I even have no idea how to go through my `ArrayList<String> linesOfFile` and mark the parts where it creates an account (if not existing) and then do the part with the transactions for each line that is indicated by the Integer above. I managed to create the accounts though but do not know how to go on.

My idea would be creating an Integer that has the same size as the number of line 1. After that I go through the file and create (if not existing) the accounts with the given balances. After each line which marks the accounts I decrement the Integer until it is 0 and end the loop. But After that I am completely lost. Maybe I could create a second loop that starts at the number that indicates the amount of transactions (line 4) and go through them until end of List?

*ANSWERED:* And how is it possible to set the last part of the transaction as one String element?
*answer:* just used a limit at .split() method.

```
Sample code would be:

ArrayList<Account> accounts;
ArrayList<String> linesOfFile = readFile("file.txt");
int count = 0;

for (String line : linesOfFile) {
    if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(0))
        count = Integer.parseInt(line);
    if (count != 0) {
        String[] accountDetails = line.split(" ");
        if (!accountExists(new Account (accountDetails[0], accountDetails[1]))) {
            accounts.add(new Account(accountDetails[0], accountDetails[1]);
        }
        count--;
    }
    // This is the part I want to add for the Transactions.
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You won't like this answer but may I ask for the use case for this?
Is this a file you create in your program somewhere else (I. E. Is this a hobby program you use for practising and the file is what could alternatively be done in a database instead ?) or is that from a real world business case where you need to import an incoming file into your system?

The reason why I'm asking is, that if possible, you could add tags in the file upon creation, to identify the fields you are reading. Alternatively of course, you should use a DB.

Comment: I do not create this file with a different program, i just create some sample files for testing.
This is just for the use of practising, I mean it is possible to create a DB with these items and  I thought about that myself, but I want to do it without anything like that.

Comment: Alright I see a few issues you should resolve before tackling the problem. First off, please add a tag to each line. Something like #noOfTrx:2 #accSender: Alice 70 #accRecipient: 50 and so on... From there, you can access the right information in the code by modifying your if statements to something like if (tag = "#noOfTrx") {count=field Value} and so on. This will help you tremendously to have easier to read code.

Comment: thanks for the hint of doing so. It is getting better and better. I still have some issues but they will leave me :)